# jQuery datetimepicker changes date when no changes are made

Tags: jquery

Im using http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ date time picker extension for jquery. Im getting a weird issue. When picker already has a value I open the pcker and then close it, nothing changes. Now if i save it and look into DB it now has the current date. It shouldnt, it should remain as it was, unless I manualli change it.

EDIT
Some code

```
jQuery('.class').datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            timeFormat: 'hh.mm.ss',
            showSecond:true
        });
```

Comment: you have added any ajax on date- picker change?

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Can you show us your code, what have you tried already?

Comment: Im currently trying to track down where the error happens. Atm im stuck at date parser. it seems date cannot be parsed and this causes error, not sure yet.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are sending the "value" if you click submit. So before showing edit page you should make datetimepickers value as which you have it on your database like

Lets assume your date is Date d on your database so;

```
//set that value with your date
<input id="d1" type="date" value="d">
```

Or at the worst case you can make a hit by jquery and set it by its ID at the end of your page